# Is the Q2 in this diagram based on J2 and K2?

Tags: digital-logic

Down here is a basic diagram Im practicing on. Im not sure if I get the answers correctly. But should I find Q2 based on J2 and K2?
X = J1 = K1
Q1 = J2* = K2
Q2
Z = Q1* + Q2*

[image]

Comment: It seems to me that you have no idea of what a flip flop is, try to learn that first. It is not that Q2 = /J1, it is exactly the opposite, namely, J1 = /Q2, since J1 is an input and /Q2 is an output

Comment: To be honest, I know very little about flip-flops, and I should study more about it. Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should find Q2 and output based on J2 and K2 inputs.  It would be better to say J1=K1, which are inputs, = X which is an output from some other circuit.  To complete this you need to know that q doesn't change for jk=00.  That Q always goes to 0 for jk=01.  Q always go to 1 for jk=10.  and q goes to q* for jk=11.  You probably noticed that Q1 is changing on the 1 to 0 transition of the clock and Q2 is changing on the 0 to 1 transition.

Comment: Thank you for your help :) Btw, before connect to the K as input, should I invert it outside of the chip first (as K internally inverted) ?

Comment: I can't say for sure but think you should not invert the K outside.  if it were inverted outside you would have a jk* flip instead of a jk.  The jk* flip flop q goes to zero if jk*=00.  Usually a jk* flip flow has a bubble on the k input.  Since I don't see that, I would guess analyze it as jk.